# Error in a recursive function to print out a series

Tags: c, recursion, math

So, I am supposed to print out the following series using a C program:

[image: 1, \frac{x^2}{2!}, \frac{x^4}{4!}, \frac{x^6}{6!}, ...]

I decide to use a recursive approach and come up with this code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

float series(int n, float x)
{
  float prod;
  if(n==1)
    return 1;
  else
  {
    prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)(2*n-3));  //line 10
    return prod*series(n-1,x);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  float x;
  printf("\n Enter the values of n and x : ");
  scanf("%d %f",&n,&x);
  printf("\n The series is :");
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    printf(" %f,",series(i,x));
  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

But this gives an error on line 10:

`error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer`

I don't see any syntactical error on the line. It would be great if you could point it out.
Thank You!

Comment: change this line prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)(2*n-3));  into this prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)*(2*n-3));   you need to put * between to brackets

Comment: @MostasimBillah The formatting of your comment got screwed up. Use backticks around the code.

Comment: `prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)(2*n-3));` ==> `prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)  *  (2*n-3));`.

Comment: ah...yes. Staring at it for 20 minutes now...was an asterisk all along. Thank you!

Comment: more importantly, you've turned a good start leading to a linear algorithm into a bad finish with the quadratic code. :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your suggestion. I will definitely remember it for future commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)(2*n-3));  //line 10
```

should be

```
prod = (x*x)/((2*n-2)*(2*n-3));  //line 10
```

The compiler sees this as a function call where `2*n-2` is the function pointer and `2*n-3` is the argument.